# How do I make aliases hidden in macOS?

Tags: terminal, folders, alias, macos

When I enter in Terminal:

```
chflags hidden location_of_alias
```

it hides the actual original folder the alias points to but it does not actually hide the alias itself.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the file flag of a symbolic link, or a Finder alias, rather than its associated file, use the `-h` option:

```
$ chflags -h hidden file
```

To  unhide a file that has the `hidden` flag set, use:

```
$ chflags -h nohidden file
```

Answer (score 2):

Filenames starting with a dot are hidden by default.
In Terminal you can rename the file with the mv command.

```
mv "old location" "new location"
```

or

```
mv path/filename path/.filename
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to make them hidden without changing the name to add a dot at the front? Let's say these files are part of a system with automated scripts. Changing their names would mess the whole system up, I presume,